# Listening to flex events in Java script without using external interface

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I need to register events in flex and listen to them in java script. Is there any way other than using external interface.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

`ExternalInterface` is the way to do it.  Why don't you want to us it?  What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: There are other ways of doing it, but they're overly complicated.  ExternalInterface is the easiest way to go.

Comment: If I use external interface i should be writing lot of internal methods for calling different javascript functions. So I want to accomplish most efficient way of doing it. If This is the only way how can I make it more efficient

Comment: Gotcha.  You want JS to register callbacks for events.  Not the other way around.  You will need to do that yourself, but it isn't terribly hard.  You will need to register JS->AS function that holds on to JS event handlers to call them back.  See this for more info: http://coderaptor.wordpress.com/2007/09/10/using-javascript-to-handle-flash-actionscript-events/

Comment: I want to use swf object to do this. Can I do that for flex to communicate with java?

Comment: You mean you have a Java applet AND a Flex SWF in the same page and you want them to talk via JavaScript?  Seems possible.